# How to access Array in UIMA-RUTA

Tags: uima, ruta

I have an Annotation class with String Array as one of the field.
I want to add and remove string elements to that String Array from ruta script.

I searched for FSArray but didn't got anything.

Please help me with solving above problem.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please read [ask] and provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

As of UIMA Ruta 2.5.0, operations on FSArrays and StringArrays are not yet supported and still an open issue: [UIMA-4399](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/UIMA-4399)

You either need to wrap the logic in an additional analysis engine or you need to write an language extension for ruta.

*DISCLAIMER: I am a developer of UIMA Ruta*

Comment: Thanks for your help. I found language extension for ruta as suitable approach for my work.